# Android webview not displaying html with external js links

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, assets

I have used the following code to display a website that i have included in the assets directory in my android app:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/my_site/index.html");
```

In the `index.html` file i have called some external js files. But the external js files are not being called. Why is this happening? I have loaded the same website locally from iOS, and it is working perfectly. What can I do to rectify this?

Comment: I have included the entire websites in the `assets` directory.

Comment: What is `gameWebView`? Shouldn't you be setting the `webSettings` for `myWebView`?

Comment: please see it now.. was actually a mistake while i typed the code here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually doing a HTML5 game using `phaser.js`. It seems like the only way out was cocoonjs. Didn't find any other solution. Why does android's webview doesn't show the game by default without using any wrappers? I had the same game working perfect in iOS and windows webview without using any kind of wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: use this webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://fake.com", myString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

Comment: What is myString? What should I give as data? null?

Comment: Nothing is happening still.

Answer (score 0):

add Internet permissions in androidManifest.xml page.

```
 <!-- Permission: Allow application to connect to Internet -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```